# Jekyll content variable returns previous post content

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, liquid

I'm trying to parse the current page HTML but `{{ content }}` returns the **previous** page HTML, not the current one.

Let's say I have 2 posts:

`2019-11-05-guy-fawkes-night.md`

```
---
---
Don't you Remember, The Fifth of November
```

`2019-11-06-stripe-cli.md`

```
---
---
An easier way to build, test, and manage your integration.
{{ content }}
```

When parsed, instead of repeating the line, `2019-11-06-stripe-cli.md` returns the following HTML:

```
An easier way to build, test, and manage your integration.
Don't you Remember,The Fifth of November
```

Comment: Hi Max!

As far as I know the primary use of `{{ content }}` is inside layout files, not within posts themselves. I don't think it'll have reliable behaviour if used in this context.

What specifically are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there's an alternative way to do this.

Comment: Something similar to what [jekyll-toc](https://github.com/allejo/jekyll-toc) does, pull the page content and extract the headers.

Comment: As far as I know there's no uncomplicated way to do this using only Liquid. And you can't run Jekyll plugins on GitHub Pages, right? I'd recommend using JavaScript, with which you could parse the resulting HTML headings and render a new element for each one.

Comment: Yes, was already considering that option. Thanks Adam!!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments to the question, this isn't the intended use of `{{ content }}`. It's meant to be used only in layout files, where it will populate the layout with the content of whatever page or post is being rendered.

Max was hoping to use this to parse the HTML of the page to render a table of contents, but we decided that using JavaScript was probably the best way to go.